# Remapping hardware key on keyboard to trigger voice input

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, voice-recognition

On my Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro running CyanogenMod 10, what I am trying to do is remap a key I never really use, like the capslock key, to trigger voice input. I know keys can be remapped changing the keymap file after your phone is rooted, but what is the syntax to assign to voice input? Is this even possible?

Comment: checking if specific key was clicked double and then assign to specific apk package name like `com.example.android.calc`